# ¿Por que no me aparece el server cuando quiero añadirlo al proyecto?

Tags: eclipse, spring

A ver estoy usando el STS Spring Tool Suit, si voy a

**menu Window -> Preferences -> server -> Runtime enviorements**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como veis esta añadido.
Pues bien, cuando voy a añadirlo al proyecto

**Boton secundario sobre el proyecto -> Properties -> Java Buid Path -> Pestaña Library-> add library->Server Runtime**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por que no aparece?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado dentro de Server Runtime?

Comment: perdon, foto equivocada un segundo

Comment: ves, dentro no aparece y no se porque.

Comment: ¿Has creado el servidor en Eclipse? Es algo que hay que hacer además del Runtime Enviroment

Comment: y donde se crea?

Comment: En la pestaña de servidores. Suele estar abajo a la izquierda en STS

Comment: vale lo estoy creando pero, en la foto que acabo de añadir ala pregunta, que selecciono ahí?

Comment: Si estas usando el de Pivotal ni idea, nunca lo he usado.